# HTML meta tag must be closed or not in XHTML?

Tags: html, xhtml, meta

I have a doubt regarding meta tag for below mentioned template

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
<title>Site Name | Page Title</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="Keyword1,Keyword2,Keyword3" >
<meta name="description" content="Page description" >
</head>
```

Should I closed meta tag like that :

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Keyword1,Keyword2,Keyword3" />
<meta name="description" content="Page description" />
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are using a transitional doctype? The transitional dtd was introduced in the previous century for the specific purpose of translating existing HTML documents to XHTML, but it was never meant to be used in new documents.

Comment: @Mr Lister : There is no specific reason!!! I am unable to choose right doctype. is this right <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: You should use `<!DOCTYPE html>`, unless you have named entity references in your document such as `&nbsp;` or `&eacute;` _AND_ you're not using any newer elements like `<picture>` or `<footer>`, in which case your best choice would be `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">`

Comment: Note that the one you're using now _does_ work, but it has the disadvantage of not flagging obsolete elements like `<font>` or `<center>` in the W3C validator.

Comment: @Mr Lister :I remember... Thanks for a helpful comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In XHTML all elements must be explicitly closed.

Difference between HTML and XHTML:

- In HTML the `<meta>` tag has no end tag.
- In XHTML the `<meta>` tag must be properly closed.

You can use the tags like:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Keyword1,Keyword2,Keyword3" >
<meta name="description" content="Page description" >
```

For more information: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: Thanks for providing w3school tutorial link.  I found this two line in w3 school -- In HTML the <meta> tag has no end tag.

In XHTML the <meta> tag must be properly closed.

Comment: Yes, you can use the meta tags without end tag in HTML, this is the answer you have been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In XHTML [all elements must be explicitly closed](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.1).

An element with content [must be closed with an end tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.3).

An element which cannot have content (such as `<meta/>`) can be closed with [either an end tag or minimized tag syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6) (unless you are writing HTML Compatible XHTML in which case [you must use minimized tag syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_2)).

An element which can have content but does not [can be closed with either an end tag or minimized tag syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6) (unless you are writing HTML Compatible XHTML in which case [you must use an explicit end tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_3)).

Comment: In line number 4    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >  .should I closed it?

Comment: @sanzuu — As I said in the first word of this answer, "Yes".